# Volley post params with multi level array is not working

Tags: arrays, android-volley, post-parameter

I am using volley `JSONObject Request`. I am trying to send multi level array in POST params, but it is not working. 
Here is my array structure.

```
[
    "param1" => "single value",
    "param2" => [123,321],
    "param3" => 112
]
```

I am not sure how to send these values.